# Nginx server variables

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

I've tried to find an example of the issue I'm facing but failed so far, so apologies if it's already been answered.

Within an nginx config (could include lua, i've tried both), I want to be able to access a variable across multiple locations within the same server. That said, I want to be able to also modify it. For example, if I do this:

```
server {
  set $asleep = 0;

  location /go_to_sleep {
    set $asleep = 1;
    echo "sleepy";
  }

  location /status {
    echo "are we asleep? $asleep";
  }
}
```

Basically I can't use params, I want a way to have a local variable that I can modify. the problem I have is that regardless of how many times I hit the /go_to_sleep endpoint, /status always reports $asleep as 0. I think it's because $asleep is only modified locally to the location endpoint of /go_to_sleep. I've tried using lua blocks too but I get the same output.

Just wondering if it's simply not possible or if anyone can help me work out how to get this sort of thing working?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Data Sharing within an Nginx Worker](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#data-sharing-within-an-nginx-worker) would work (as clearly stated) within nginx worker. If it is what you want - please take a look at Paul Kulchenko's answer.

But if you need global flags across workers you may use [ngx.shared.DICT API](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxshareddict)

```
http {
    lua_shared_dict my_global_flags 10m;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location = /go_to_sleep {
            content_by_lua_block {
                local my_global_flags = ngx.shared.my_global_flags
                my_gobal_flags:set("asleep" , true)
                ngx.say("sleepy")
            }
        }

        location /status {
            content_by_lua_block {
                local my_global_flags = ngx.shared.my_global_flags
                ngx.say("are we asleep ", my_gobal_flags:get("asleep"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that is perfect and exactly what i needed. Paul I did try your suggestion and it did work but this remove my need to have any lua files so it's a win for me. Thank you both

Comment: There is a big difference in using shared dictionary and per-module-state: If you have more then one nginx worker the last method will not works, because every nginx worker has its own copy on  all loaded modules.  /go_to_sleepy request may be processed by worker one, but /status request may be processed by others workers. For me it looks like a reason to choice shared dictionary, not because it doesn't require lua module.

Answer (score 0):

Given the recommendation in [Data Sharing within an Nginx Worker](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#data-sharing-within-an-nginx-worker), I think you may need to switch to using modules to share data values, as shown and explained in that example. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186423/what-is-the-concurrency-model-in-openresty) question/answer and the example in it may also be relevant.